# Is it possible to Add .pch File in project?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I Download Project for learning purpose.  But in this project i got error that is display in MY Screen Shot . i know that Prefix headers are compiled and stored in a cache, and then automatically included in every file during compilation. This can speed up compilation, and lets you include a file without adding an import statement to every file using it. They are not required, and actually slow compilation whenever you change them.

**Screenshot**
[image]

My Question is that is it possible in my case  to add .pch file or not ??? if possible then please explain it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The fact that it is in red means that Xcode is unable to find the file.  Also, the error you showed is meaningless, you have to look further up the output to get the real one.

Comment: If you want .pch not to be compiled, check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728225/is-it-ok-to-remove-prefix-pch-file-from-the-xcode-project

Comment: Check whether that file is present in the folder. The error says that file is not there in your folder.

Comment: thanks for replay...yes i got .. it is not possible because this file are not in my project folder :( but i ask this question because i am new at iPhone Development...so thanks to all for more clear my idea :)

Comment: Please do more research into what the tags you're editing into questions mean. You've recently performed several very incorrect retags.

Comment: @0x7fffffff- okay iphone tag is not require in this Que. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot shows that you do not have the pch file added to the physical folder or it is removed somehow from there even though it is added to the project. You need to add that file again and build to remove this error. You can remove the reference from project before doing that and add it as a new file to this project once you have added it in your physical folder.

A red file name in project as shown in screenshot normally represents a missing file from the project folder structure.

Comment: yes ... i added .pch file and remove this error :) thanks for help me :)