# What is Prefix.pch file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

So many developers are adding various convenience macros to the `Prefix.pch`. But my question is what is that `Prefix.pch` file.

- If i remove that `Prefix.pch` file from my `Xcode`, then will my application run? Or will it show any error? Or will it crash during build?
- How can i run my application without `Prefix.pch` file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it OK to remove Prefix.pch file from the Xcode project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728225/is-it-ok-to-remove-prefix-pch-file-from-the-xcode-project)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

## Precompiled header.

#### What is it?

A `Prefix.pch` is a precompiled header. Precompiled headers were invented **to make compiling faster**. Rather than parsing the same header files over and over, these files get parsed once, ahead of time.

#### Xcode

In Xcode, you add imports of the header files you want in a “prefix header,” and enabling `Precompile Prefix Header` so they get precompiled. But the idea behind a prefix header is different from precompiling.

A prefix header is implicitly included at the start of every source file. It’s like each source file adds

```
#import "Prefix.pch"
```

at the top of the file, before anything else.

#### Removing it.

You can remove the precompiled header. This question has been already answered in thread I'm linking below. It contains all the information you need as well as useful comments.

[Is it OK to remove Prefix.pch file from the Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728225/is-it-ok-to-remove-prefix-pch-file-from-the-xcode-project)

Answer (score 29):

## What is Prefix.pch file?

A .pch is a Pre-Compiled Header.

In the C and C++ programming languages, a header file is a file whose text may be automatically included in another source file by the C preprocessor, usually specified by the use of compiler directives in the source file.

Prefix headers are compiled and stored in a cache, and then automatically included in every file during compilation. This can speed up compilation, and lets you include a file without adding an import statement to every file using it. They are not required, and actually slow compilation whenever you change them.

## Yes, you can compile and run the project without .pch file

In Xcode, go to your target's build settings (Command-Option-E, build tab) and uncheck Precompile Prefix Header (GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER). You can also remove the value of the Prefix Header setting if you wish.

## Also note that,

Don't put macros in a.pch file! A .pch file is, by definition, a project specific precompiled header. It really shouldn't be used beyond the context of the project and it really shouldn't contain anything but #includes and #imports.

If you have some macros and such that you want to share between headers, then stick 'em in a header file of their own — Common.h or whatever — and #include that at the beginning of the .pch

Comment: It's probably because you copied and pasted, without attribution, the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728225/is-it-ok-to-remove-prefix-pch-file-from-the-xcode-project

Comment: Thanks for stopping by @BenButterworth on this old answer, when I answered I might missed the attribution, but if you look closely have changed and divide the questions and copied the answer from the one which you mentioned. Thanks for letting me know and now rectifying this. However, I don't remember from which other source have copied the remaining piece of answer.

Answer (score 8):

Prefix headers are compiled and stored in a cache, and then automatically included in every file during compilation. This can speed up compilation, and lets you include a file without adding an import statement to every file using it. They are not required, and actually slow compilation whenever you change them.

Generally `.pch` file naming formation is `yourProjectName-Prefix.pch`

Answer (score 2):

**Prefix Headers and Precompiled Headers (.pch)**

**History:**

[[#include -> #import]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212007/4770877) -> Precompiled Headers .pch -> [[@import Module(ObjC);]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213796/4770877) -> [[import Module(Swift)]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67130959/4770877)

**Precompiled Headers - prefix.pch**

To create new .pch file

```
File -> New -> File... -> PCH File
```

`PrefixHeader.pch` sample:

```
#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

From Xcode 6 you should set `.pch` manually. Previously it was called `<product_name>-Prefix.pch`

**Xcode:**

[image]

`Prefix Header(GCC_PREFIX_HEADER)` - path to `.pch`. Adds all content from  `.pch` to **all** source files

SomeFile1.h

```
//You can skip this section. It will be compiled 
//#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//implicitly next line is used
#import "PrefixHeader.pch"
```

`Precompile Prefix Header(GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER)` - When **Yes** then `Prefix headers` from `GCC_PREFIX_HEADER` will be used once* to generate precompiled sources and will be stored in a cache which speeds up a build time

```
//path to cached precompiled headers
/<some_path>/DerivedData/ExperiementsModuleSwift-dsetoksxykdmgvczgtnmaqmjwhzk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/14385052922615550324
//e.g
/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExperiementsModuleSwift-dsetoksxykdmgvczgtnmaqmjwhzk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/14385052922615550324
```

[image]

**#import vs .pch**

This feature improves **build time**(comparing with `#include/#import`) because **precompiles** a `prefix headers`(global). When some content of `prefix headers` is changed it means that Compiles must recompile that again. that is why you should use stable(not often changeable) `prefix headers` here or you dont't see build time improvement. Also you should support it