# How to to import headers automatically in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header

Is there any way to import a common header for whole project only once? The idea is place on that header the `#defines` that will enable/disable functionalities.

I do not want to write `#import "common.h"` on every `.m` file.

Comment: Write down your header in .pch file ...it will be global for whole project..

Comment: The question is clear. A common automatic header for putting GLOBAL defines For other use, is not recommended at all.

Comment: @JavierCalatravaLlavería Why is that so?

Comment: This is very useful when you want to create with the same base of software different products enabling/disabling some of its features. You have a common place where to set the #defines and you do not have to worry about import the header that has the #define

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Add your common file to the project:

[image]

Then edit the .pch file from your project and import your common.h file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
...
    #import "Common.h"
#endif
```

Finally the Common.h you can place the #defines:

```
#define FEATURE_A 0
#define FEATURE_B 1
```

ALL the stuff that you put in Common.h will be loaded automatically on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix headers are commonly used for this purpose; although some advocate against using them.

Reference: [What is Prefix.pch file in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648593/what-is-prefix-pch-file-in-xcode), http://qualitycoding.org/precompiled-headers/

Comment: I advocate use them, ONLY AND ONLY IF, you put in them global #defines.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Javier's answer, but you probably also need to create and set up your `pch` file now, as xcode doesn't automatically create it anymore. To do so, create a new file, select Other under iOS, and select `PCH File`. Name it ProjectNamePrefix.pch where ProjectName is your project's name.

Then after you create it, you need to go to your build settings, search for prefix. And under the section `Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language` you'll see a section called `Prefix Header`. Make the value of the file name you just created. Build, and your good.

Anything you import or define in this file will be available in all of your files