# Why does importing a ViewController cause Xcode to not be able to find another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

My project structure/dependencies are:

**AppDelegate** --> Imports "FirstRunViewController" and "MainViewController"

- If the user is logged in, it sets the rootViewController to MainViewController
- If the user is not logged in, it sets the rootViewController to FirstRunViewController

**FirstRunViewController** --> Imports "MainViewController"

- After login/sign up, it sets the viewController as MainViewController

**MainViewController** --> Imports "SettingsViewController"

- Presents SettingsViewController when needed

**SettingsViewController** --> Imports "FirstRunViewController"

- If the user chooses to log out, it sets the viewController as FirstRunViewController

**My Issue**

Importing "FirstRunViewController" in "SettingsViewController" (to handle logging out) causes Xcode to not be able to find a valid delegate in another, unrelated ViewController. The specific error code is "No type or protocol named ABCDelegate".

Deleting that "#import" statement will allow the code to run and compile, but disables logging out.

**My Question**

Why does this happen?

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: But where is ABCDelegate declared? Also please show the actual import statements and where they are: do not just say "imports" because who knows what you're really doing? Don't _describe_ your code; _show_ it. Much more reliable and clear if you do.

Comment: Try using `@class` instead `import`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a circular dependency issue.  I'll explain with an example.

A imports B.  A requires B to already be compiled so it can refer to its methods.  We say that B is a dependency of A.  So Xcode automatically arranges the order in which it compiles things:

1. B
2. A

So that when A is compiled, B is already compiled.  However, what happens when we add a third class, C.  C imports A, but B imports C.

1. B
2. A
3. C

But now when the compiler tries to compile B, C has not been compiled so it complains that it cannot find C.

But simply changing the order won't change things because C requires A but A requires B but B requires C.  It's a circular dependency.

One way to solve this is to create a precompiled header (see the question that Badal Shah linked).  This solves the problem by essentially promising that C exists and just hasn't been compiled yet, and will let B compile successfully which lets the whole loop compile successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure . But with your flow i can feel like This occurs because of **circular dependency**.

**Solution :-**

Use .pch file and import your all file in .pch file and use it according to your requirement.

Regarding detail discussion on **.pch** file check this .

[what-is-prefix-pch-file-in-xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648593/what-is-prefix-pch-file-in-xcode)