# Use classes without import header

Tags: objective-c, import, header

I have some weird codes.

ClassA.h

```objectivec
// there is no import code
@protocol Album <Meta>
@end

@interface MyAlbum: VariantMeta <Album>
@end
```

What I know is this.

If I want to use any classes which are declared from outside of current file (in this case `Meta` and `VariantMeta`) I have to import those classes header files.

But `Class.h` can use `Meta` without imports any headers.
There should be `#import 'Meta.h';` in my understanding.
But there is not!

Can I get any hints for understanding this situation?
help me

thanks

## Update

Class.m file looks like this.

```objectivec
// Class.m
#import <Framework/SomeHeaderWhichImportMetaHeaderFile>
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation MyAlbum
@end
```

I guess this `Class.m` file's `import`, somehow, affects `header` file. but I don't know how it can be...

Comment: Check if there is a file named `YourApp-Prefix.pch`, if yes, that's why. In a nutshell, it will add to all your files its list of imports  (including also macros, etc.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648593/what-is-prefix-pch-file-in-xcode

Comment: @Larme I searched a pch file and there is no such file. and I update my question.

Comment: Is `Meta.h` imported by `<Framework/SomeHeaderWhichImportMetaHeaderFile>` or `ClassA.h`? Try `#import "ClassA.h"` before `#import <Framework/SomeHeaderWhichImportMetaHeaderFile>`.